# i am getting exceptiion like below

Tags: android

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
                    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                     double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                     double latitude = location.getLatitude();


                if(location == null){
                   longitude = 0.0;
                   latitude = 0.0;
                   Log.i("CURRENT LONGITUDE", ""+longitude);
                   Log.i("CURRENT LATITUDE", ""+latitude);
                }

                Log.i("CURRENT LONGITUDE", ""+longitude);
                Log.i("CURRENT LATITUDE", ""+latitude);
```

I am getting  problem at line  "double longitude = location.getLongitude();" which is line 93 in MainActivity;

```
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at com.demo.parsing.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:93)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-18 16:52:26.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you add the whole stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is strange:

```
  double longitude = location.getLongitude();
  double latitude = location.getLatitude();
  if(location == null){
```

It seems you expect that location can be NULL. But the two lines above that use location to call a member function. If it is NULL, then you will get a nullpointerexception.

in response to your comment: You could easily fix it by changing the order of things:

```
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
double latitude;
double longitude;
if(location == null){
    longitude = 0.0;
    latitude = 0.0;
    Log.i("CURRENT LONGITUDE", ""+longitude);
    Log.i("CURRENT LATITUDE", ""+latitude);
}else{
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
}
```

Edit 2
If you would just take a quick look at the manual:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

you would have read this: (emph mine)

> Returns a Location indicating the data
>   from the last known location fix
>   obtained from the given provider. This
>   can be done without starting the
>   provider. Note that this location
>   could be out-of-date, for example if
>   the device was turned off and moved to
>   another location. **If the provider is
>   currently disabled, null is returned.**

Comment: yes friend you are right so what should i do if am getting null longitude or latitude

Comment: Not tested, so there could be a minor bug in there, but the idea is clear: check first, assign later :)

Comment: yes i fixed it by your help.. and i want to know that if i am getting null longitude and latitude then what is the reason behind that...

Answer (score 1):

You check if location is null only after you used it. It might be null during assignment to longtitude /latitude.

Comment: if i am getting null longitude or latitude so , what should i do?